# Retrieved value from database. How to set to Action Form and JSP from Action class?

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I have Checkbox in jsp. I want to set its value based on the value retrieved from database.

I have retrieved the value in action class but i am not able to set this value from action class to jsp page.

I am newbie. Could anyone please tell how to do this.

JSP:

```
    <html:form action="faxDownloadSettings">
    <html:hidden property="checkMe"/>
    <input type=checkbox name="pdf" property="checkMe" checked="checked"> <bean:message key="com.console.asPDF"/>
    <console:button name="save" script="save();">
    <console:label><bean:message key="com.console.save"/></console:label>
    </console:button>
```

Action form:

```
    public class FaxDownloadSettingsForm extends ActionForm {


    private boolean checkMe;

    public void setCheckMe(boolean checkMe){
                    this.checkMe = checkMe;
            }

            public boolean getCheckMe(){
                    return checkMe;
            }
    }
```

Action class:

```
    public class FaxDownloadSettingsAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                            ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response)
                                            throws Exception {

     FaxDownloadSettingsForm form = (FaxDownloadSettingsForm) actionForm;

      boolean isFaxtopdf = enumResponse.getFaxtopdf();

      request.setAttribute("checkFax", isFaxtopdf);

      form.setCheckMe(true); //It also not works    

    }

return mapping.findForward("success");


    }
```

Comment: Why can't you initialize the `ActionForm` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action's execute method, set the attribute at request level like:

```
request.setAttribute("vehicleSelected", getVehicleFromDB());
```

In your jsp, you could do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="${vehicleSelected}"/>
```

Comment: Since it's Struts 1 it'd be better to use the existing framework mechanisms for this, e.g., the `ActionForm`.

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to do this. But form gets reset on page load. Sending the small code snapshot for the same.

Comment: @k00989 That's what `ActionForm.reset` is for.

Comment: @almas shaikh I have followed your steps and got the solution. I uses Expression language and set the value from form itself.